# Why does `p var if var = 0.zero?` raise an error?

Tags: ruby

I was recently given this as a hard programming question:

> What is the output of `p var if var = 0.zero?`(question mark is part of the code).

My assumption is that first `0.zero?` would be evaluated, return `true`, then `var = true`, which would set `var` to `true` and return `true`, so `p var if true` would then print `true`.

But this is not what happens. Ruby raises an error `` undefined local variable or method `var' ... ``

```
p var if var = 0.zero?
# => NameError: undefined local variable or method `var' for main:Object
from (irb):19
from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

p var if var = (0.zero?)
# => true

p var if (var = 0).zero?
# => 0

p var if (var = 0.zero?)
# => true

p var if var = 0
# => (irb):23: warning: found = in conditional, should be == 0
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Local Variables and Methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods)

> The local variable is created when the parser encounters the
>   assignment, not when the assignment occurs